# Magento 2 upload category image with the same name but different image

Tags: magento2, category, image, upload

Magento 2 upload category image with the same name but different image

I am trying to compress the category images and upload with the image with the same name but it's adding "_2.jpg" to it.
Ex: "image_2.jpg"

is it possible to upload a different image with the same name?

Comment: You need to delete the previous image if that is associated with that particular category. Because Magento always add _1,_2 with image name when uploading if they find that image is already exist.

Comment: Thanks, it's working as expected, Before posting the question I deleted the previous image and uploaded my image what I did the mistake didn't clear browser cache.

Comment: Great! Happy Coding.